# Read contents of an Excel file using PowerShell and store it in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, excel, powershell

I am trying to write the contents of an Excel file (on tab 5) to a database but it keeps failing.

Here is my code:

```
 $dir = "\\server\files\"
    $latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*Data Notes*"} | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
    Write-Output "The latest file is: $latest"
    Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance "sql server" -DatabaseName "sql5" -SchemaName dbo -TableName Temptable100 -InputData $latest.FullName -Force
```

The table gets created fine but its empty. Can anyone please help me??

I have attached the contents of the Excel file here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Write-SQLTableData won't be able to read an Excel file so you will need to use something like OLEDB to first read the Excel table into a DataTable and then pass that DataTable to Write-SQLTableData.

Comment: @ Hislop, how can that be done? am a bit new to powershell

Answer (score 0):

All I needed was to store the information in a data variable and then use the Write-SQLTableData to store the information in a database. See below:

```
Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance "instance" -DatabaseName "db1" -SchemaName dbo -TableName TableName -InputData $DataTable -Force
```